# Synchronous function calls involving post json calls where one function should succeed upon the success of another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post

I have two functions one of which includes multiple json call which are post by nature.

I want these to be synchronous. That is, one should run only upon the completion of the previous post (and if all posts are done and successful I want the second function to fire).

The code structure is somewhat like this:

```
    $.getSomeData = function() {
    $.postJSON("iwantdata.htm",{data:data},function(data)){
    });

    $.postJSON("iwantmoredata.htm",{data:data},function(data)){
    });
    });

    $.useSomeData = function() {
});
```

The `useSomeData` must work upon subsequent json calls.

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest editing your answer and title to remove occurrences of the word "synchronous". This is not what "synchronous" means in JSON (an XML HTTP Request is synchronous if it waits for the server to continue processing client-side code, usually a bad thing). Are you looking for the word "atomic" which means that they either both succeed or both fail? Or do you want to just chain these such that once you get the first output back, you ask for more output... but with the caveat that if one thing fails, the chain stops processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want something like this:

```
function chainPost(url1, url2, initialInput, func) {
    $.post(url1, {data: initialInput})
        .done(function (initialOutput) {
            $.post(url2, {data: initialOutput})
                .done(function (secondOutput) {
                    func(initialOutput, secondOutput);
                });
        });
}

chainPost("iwantdata.htm", "iwantmoredata.htm", 0, function (first, second) {
    alert(first);
    alert(second);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just nest them, starting the 2nd one in the completion function of the first and so on:

```
$.getSomeData = function() {
   $.postJSON("iwantdata.htm",{data:data},function(data) {
       $.postJSON("iwantmoredata.htm",{data:data},function(data)){
           // use the data here
       });
   });
};
```

When dealing with asychronous functions, you cannot write code such as:

```
$.getSomeData();
$.useSomeData();
```

By definition, the first is asynchronous so it will not have completed yet with the second function is called and javascript does not have the ability to stop JS execution until an asynchronous operation is done.

You could pass your use function to the get function and then it would get called when the data was available as an addition to the above example like this:

```
$.getSomeData = function(fn) {
   $.postJSON("iwantdata.htm",{data:data},function(data) {
       $.postJSON("iwantmoredata.htm",{data:data},function(data)){
           fn(data);
       });
   });
};
```

Then, you'd have a `getSomeData(useFn)` function that would take an argument of the function to call when all the data was ready.

Answer (score 1):

[Deferred objects *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) are perfect for this. Unfortunately, your code example contains syntax errors and it is not clear how the calls are nested. So, I'm not sure if you want to run both Ajax calls after one another or parallel, but either way is possible.

Here are two examples. Have a look at the documentation for more information and play around with it.

**Note:** `.postJSON` is not a built in jQuery method, I assume here that you are returning the return value from the `$.ajax` (or `$.post`) function.

**Parallel Ajax calls:**

```
$.getSomeData = function() {
    var a = $.postJSON("iwantdata.htm", {data:data});
    var b = $.postJSON("iwantmoredata.htm", {data:data});

    // return a new promise object which gets resolved when both calls are
    // successful
    return $.when(a, b);
};

// when both calls are successful, call `$.useSomeData`
// it will have access to the responses of both Ajax calls
$.getSomeData.done($.useSomeData);
```

*See:* [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

**Chained Ajax calls:**

... where the response of the first call is the input for the second one. This is only an example, of course you can pass any data you want.

```
$.getSomeData = function() {
    return $.postJSON("iwantdata.htm", {data:data}).pipe(function(response) {
        // execute the second Ajax call upon successful completion 
        // of the first one
        return $.postJSON("iwantmoredata.htm", {data:response});
    });
};

// if both Ajax calls are successful, call `$.useSomeData`
// it will have access to the response of the second Ajax call
$.getSomeData.done($.useSomeData);
```

*See:* [`deferred.pipe()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/)

If you have a more complex logic, you can also create, resolve or reject your own deferred objects. Have a look at the examples in the documentation.

Comment: Note that your chained example uses the result of the first call as arguments to the second call

Comment: @Bergi: Yes, it seemed to make the most sense that way... it's just an example.

Comment: That's true - the only reason for chaining them is that #2 needs data from #1 :-)

Comment: @Bergi - using returned data is not the only reason for chaining.  #2 may just be the second operation in a sequence and needs to wait to see if #1 was successful, but doesn't need a result from #1.  There could also be a back-end reason that the operations have to be sequenced.